# DefaultControllerFactory extensibility examples

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, extensibility

One of the major advantages with asp.net MVC is extensibility. We can even extend Default Controller Factory by overriding methods of `DefaultControllerFactory`.

My question is when should we extend controller factory,Can someone please tell me one of the real time scenarios where we might need to extend `DefaultControllerFactory`  and why we need to extend that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when should we extend controller factory

This is kind of a backwards question... You swap or extend the default controller factory when the default controller factory doesn't satisfy your needs.

So if you haven't run into a situation where you said *"Oh my, I can't do this with the default controller factory"*, then you don't need it.

It's generally only needed for dependency injection through constructor injection, as the default controller factory only supports parameterless constructors.

Most DI frameworks come with their own controller factory, usually in a `DIFramework.Mvc{version}` NuGet package (e.g. [Unity.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/)).